# How to take out white borders in JMenu and JMenuItems

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem, jmenubar

I'm doing this Graphic Interface with Swing. The problem that i'm having is that i can't take the white borders that are arround the JMenuItems, and paint it all of black. Here is an image:

[image]

I would like to paint it like this (I have edited the image with paint :D):

[image]

Could someone help me? I'll appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Is this all of the code that assembles the components?

Comment: I've not looked into this, but as I recall, the popup is generated from the look and feel delegate, in a not so easy way to intercept or control

Comment: You might try having a look at the `PopupMenu.border` `UIManager` property, but this would effect ALL popup menus

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just did this quick test, using

`UIManager.put("PopupMenu.border", new LineBorder(Color.RED));`

[image: Test]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                UIManager.put("PopupMenu.border", new LineBorder(Color.RED));

                JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
                JMenu menu = new JMenu("Stuff");
                menu.add(new JMenuItem("A"));
                menu.add(new JMenuItem("BB"));
                menu.add(new JMenuItem("CCC"));
                menuBar.add(menu);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

Now, this may not be desirable, as this will effect ALL popup menus in your program

**Updated**

I had a look at `JMenu` and through it's UI delegates and it appears that the popup menu is created within a `private` method of `JMenu` called `ensurePopupMenuCreated`, which would have been an excellent place to inject your custom code.

The method is actually called in a number of different places, but possibly the `getPopupMenu` is the most accessible

[image: Help]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
                JMenu menu = new JMenu("Stuff") {
                    private Border border = new LineBorder(Color.RED);
                    @Override
                    public JPopupMenu getPopupMenu() {
                        JPopupMenu menu = super.getPopupMenu();
                        menu.setBorder(border);
                        return menu;
                    }

                };
                JMenuItem mi = new JMenuItem("Help", 'H');
                mi.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_H, KeyEvent.META_MASK));
                menu.add(new JMenuItem("A"));
                menu.add(new JMenuItem("BB"));
                menu.add(new JMenuItem("CCC"));
                menu.add(mi);
                menuBar.add(menu);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: @LuxxMiner That would depend on what you're trying to achieve and how much assess you have to the underlying code and if your really want to apply a `Border` to EVERY `JMenu` you create, instead of using a single line of code or a custom class to effect it ;)

Comment: @LuxxMiner That and I wanted to dig deeper into how the popup was actually created ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am adding a second approach. You could use `setBorder` method:

```
menuBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 2));
```

This solution has the advantage that you can set the level of thickness. In the example above level of thickness is set to 2.

Also you can use setBorder in many components to paint various borders as in the example below:

First the basic code:

**Main class:**

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            CustomGUI sw = new CustomGUI();
            sw.setVisible(true);
        });

    }
}
```

**CustomGui.class:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CustomGUI extends JFrame {

    public CustomGUI()  {
        super("Simple example");
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        setSize(500,500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);



        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu1 = new JMenu("menu B");
        menuBar.add(menu1);

        JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("A text-only menu item");
        menu1.add(item);

        JMenu menu2 = new JMenu("menu B");
        menuBar.add(menu2);

        JMenuItem item2 = new JMenuItem("A text-only menu item");
        menu2.add(item2);


        add(menuBar);
    }
}
```

Now by adding line:

```
menuBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 2));
```

in `CustomGUI()` we get:
[image]

Now if we want to add border to jmenu's (which is what the OP asked) as well add:

```
menu1.getPopupMenu().setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 4));
menu2.getPopupMenu().setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 4));
```

[image]
(as you can see in the image i didn't set border for menubar but this could be done as described above using:
`menuBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 2));` 
And also I added another item just for the menu to be bigger and easier to see the border...)